# What is the meaning of bind = True keyword in celery?

Tags: python, django, celery

What is the meaning of `bind=True` in below **celery** code? When to use it and when not?

```
@app.task(bind=True)
def send_twitter_status(self, oauth, tweet):
    try:
        twitter = Twitter(oauth)
        twitter.update_status(tweet)
    except (Twitter.FailWhaleError, Twitter.LoginError) as exc:
        raise self.retry(exc=exc)
```

Answer (score 89, accepted):

Just a small addition to other answers. As already stated, [bound tasks](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/tasks.html#bound-tasks) have access to the task instance. One use case when this is needed are retries:

```
@celery.task(bind=True, max_retries=5)
def retrying(self):
    try:
        return 1/0
    except Exception:
        self.retry(countdown=5)
```

Another use case is when you want to define [custom states](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/tasks.html#custom-states) for your tasks and be able to set it during task execution:

```
@celery.task(bind=True)
def show_progress(self, n):
    for i in range(n):
        self.update_state(state='PROGRESS', meta={'current': i, 'total': n})
```

Comment: If you don't use `bind` the you can still reference the same object by using the function name.  In your first example you can use `retrying.retry(countdown=5)` and in the 2nd `show_progress.update_state()`.

Answer (score 39):

**Bound tasks**

A task being bound means the first argument to the task will always be the task instance (self), just like *Python bound methods*:

```
logger = get_task_logger(__name__)

@task(bind=True)
def add(self, x, y):
    logger.info(self.request.id)
```

Answer (score 16):

> The bind argument means that the function will be a “bound method” so that you can access attributes and methods on the task type instance.

See the [docs](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/tasks.html)